# Is it possible to "pause" a drop event when sorting to ask a user a question (jquery-ui sortable)?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am working on a project which uses the [jquery-ui sortable](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/) widget.

Under certain circumstance, I need to ask the user a question that relates to the sort, then the `update` callback will behave differently depending on their answer.

I have this working using the built in `confirm` function, however I need to be able to customize the buttons, which is not possible. Jsfiddle linked below.

If I switch to a custom prompt then I don't think I can make it blocking, which means the sort finishes before the user has answered the question.

Is there a way I can "pause" the sort until the user has answered the question, so I can end up with the equivalent functionality of the below example, but with a customized confirm dialog?

For the purposes of this question, we can assume that the custom confirm dialog could be called as follows (based on the code in the jsfiddle):

```
beforeStop:function(e,u) {
  // Pause the sort

  customConfirmDialog("Do you want to do something special?", function(result) {
    if (result) {
      // They said yes
      u.item.addClass("special");
     }

     // Allow the sort to continue here

  });
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/at1s6w9b/)

Comment: No good way to "pause" the sort with sortable. The User is still dragging the item (mouse button down). When the User stops dragging (mouse button up), the item is dropped and `beforeStop` is triggered. You could do it with a custom Drag and Drop, where when drag is stopped, you pose the query, and perform a drop-like event after they confirm one way or the other, modifying the item before dropping it.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs for the [cancel method](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-cancel) it say:

> Cancels a change in the current sortable and reverts it to the state prior to when the current sort was started. Useful in the stop and receive callback functions.

I assume that you could always cancel the event and then move the item yourself  once they confirm. You can probably record the [previous](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) sibling of the placeholder (or itself if in the stop method, I guess) in order to know where to place it (will be empty if moving to the top of the list).

You may need to use [refresh](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refresh) and/or [refreshPositions](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-refreshPositions) as well in order to make everything work (I'm guessing `refreshPositions`).

Comment: That would be ugly because it would put the item back in its original position while the user is answering the question. I would prefer to leave it hovering where they are dropping it until they've decided if possible.

Comment: Then perhaps the opposite? Add the class when confirmed else manually move the item back if that's something you're trying to achieve?

Comment: The item doesn't get moved back, it changes what is sent to the server on update, which may result in other items getting automatically moved. That might have to be the way I do it if no-one suggests a way to pause the sort as per my question. Thanks!

Comment: Anything thing that was JS based has to be asynchronous, else it would be freezing the UI thread and you wouldn't be able to click on anything anyway (there would be no JS thread to handle the click whilst the Sortable thread was blocked, since JS doesn't have threads). It's only possible with confirm/alert/prompt since the browser is rendering it for you and so it can be interacted with while blocking JS for the entire tab.